# Aggregate function error when ORDER BY on timeStamp Access VBA / Excel

Tags: excel, ms-access, sql-order-by, vba

An Access database contains logData of a machinepark. For management purposes I need to have some Figures, which are generated using Excel. The data is obtained from Access using VBA queries. So far, so good.
Besides a dateStamp, a weeknumber is stored as well (as Access/Excel has issues with ISO weeknumber). However, if I extract data for January 2016, it not only contains week 1-4 but week 53 of 2016 as well. I want to sort it 53, 1, 2, 3, 4. 
This last step fails with an Error:

> "Your query does not include the specified expression Format$(logData.dateStamp,'yyyy/mm') as part of an
>   aggregate function."

With the SQL query below:

```
TRANSFORM  sum((logData.hoursDay+logData.hoursNight)*60) 
SELECT reasons.reason FROM reasons 
INNER JOIN (logData INNER JOIN testRigs ON logData.machine = machines.ID) ON reasons.ID = logData.reason 
WHERE  Format$(logData.dateStamp,'mm') =  1  
AND machines.type = "A" 
GROUP BY reasons.reason 
ORDER BY Format$(logData.dateStamp,'yyyy/mm') DESC
PIVOT logData.week;
```

Aggregate functions such as AVG() and COUNT() can be but in the SELECT statement, but I don't need this column.

Any tips how to get the weeks sorted correctly?

Comment: If you can't have that expression in the _Group By_ section, you will have to remove it and the _Order By_ section and _Pivot_ on not the week but the year-and-week. See function below.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to store the weeknumber but, for a given date, you will have to find both the year and the week to obtain correct sorting.

This function does that:

```
Public Function ISO_WeekYearNumber( _
  ByVal datDate As Date, _
  Optional ByRef intYear As Integer, _
  Optional ByRef bytWeek As Byte) _
  As String

' Calculates and returns year and week number for date datDate according to the ISO 8601:1988 standard.
' Optionally returns numeric year and week.
' 1998-2007, Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
' May be freely used and distributed.

  Const cbytFirstWeekOfAnyYear  As Byte = 1
  Const cbytLastWeekOfLeapYear  As Byte = 53
  Const cbytMonthJanuary        As Byte = 1
  Const cbytMonthDecember       As Byte = 12
  Const cstrSeparatorYearWeek   As String = "W"

  Dim bytMonth                  As Byte
  Dim bytISOThursday            As Byte
  Dim datLastDayOfYear          As Date

  intYear = Year(datDate)
  bytMonth = Month(datDate)
  bytWeek = DatePart("ww", datDate, vbMonday, vbFirstFourDays)

  If bytWeek = cbytLastWeekOfLeapYear Then
    bytISOThursday = Weekday(vbThursday, vbMonday)
    datLastDayOfYear = DateSerial(intYear, cbytMonthDecember, 31)
    If Weekday(datLastDayOfYear, vbMonday) >= bytISOThursday Then
      ' OK, week count of 53 is caused by leap year.
    Else
      ' Correct for Access97/2000+ bug.
      bytWeek = cbytFirstWeekOfAnyYear
    End If
  End If

  ' Adjust year where week number belongs to next or previous year.
  If bytMonth = cbytMonthJanuary Then
    If bytWeek >= cbytLastWeekOfLeapYear - 1 Then
      ' This is an early date of January belonging to the last week of the previous year.
      intYear = intYear - 1
    End If
  ElseIf bytMonth = cbytMonthDecember Then
    If bytWeek = cbytFirstWeekOfAnyYear Then
      ' This is a late date of December belonging to the first week of the next year.
      intYear = intYear + 1
    End If
  End If

  ISO_WeekYearNumber = CStr(intYear) & cstrSeparatorYearWeek & Format(bytWeek, "00")

End Function
```